# I am unable to extend my activity to listactivity

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
// private ListView lView;
 private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
 PackageInfo pInfo;
 String packageName;
 String app;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//  lView= findViewById(R.id.list);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List < ResolveInfo > list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo: list) {
        results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
            .loadLabel(pm).toString());
        Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
            .loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }
            getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
}


 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    pInfo= (PackageInfo) results.get(arg2);
    app= (String) results.get(arg2);
    packageName = pInfo .packageName;
    try {
        Class myapp= Class.forName(packageName + app);
        Intent myintent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, myapp);
        startActivity(myintent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is my recent code. but i am getting the same error again and again.

```
05-15 17:19:52.383: E/AndroidRuntime(6370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ku.installedapps/com.ku.installedapps.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

help needded. M getting the same error as previous. :(

Comment: > Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: You need to add a list view in your `activity_main.xml` with `android:id="@+id/list"`

Answer (score 1):

In your XML, make sure you have a `ListView` who has the android ID, like this:

Instead of your XML:
`<ListView android:id="@+id/list"` , Use this:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" ...>
```

Comment: MY xml file ...

<LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
 
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    />
 
</LinearLayout>